# Как изменить рамку у выбранной ячейки JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Здравствуйте!
Это мой первый вопрос на StackoverFlow, поэтому заранее извиняюсь если он покажется некорректным!
Знаю, что есть куча обсуждений по поводу отрисовки JTable, в том числе и на этом сайте, но описания моей проблемы не нашел нигде.
Вопрос следующий: как изменит цвет рамки у ячейки JTable, по которой щелкнули дважды?
Приведу код своего рисовальщика:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JLabel cell = new JLabel();
    cell.setText(value != null ? value.toString() : null);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    cell.setOpaque(true);
    if (row == 0 || column == 0) {
        cell.setBackground(new Color(240, 255, 255));
        if (hasFocus) {
            cell.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(99, 130, 191)));
            cell.setBackground(new Color(155, 228, 181));
        } else {
            cell.setBorder(new LineBorder(null, 0));
            cell.setBackground(new Color(240, 255, 255));
        }
        if (row == 0) {
            if (column == 0) {
                cell.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            } else {
                cell.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            }
        } else {
            cell.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
        }
    } else {
        cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        cell.setBorder(new LineBorder(null, 0));
        if (hasFocus) {
            cell.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(99, 130, 191)));
            cell.setBackground(new Color(155, 228, 181));
        } else {
            cell.setBorder(new LineBorder(null, 0));
            cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

У меня получилось изменить цвет и рамку заголовков, так же получилось изменить цвет и рамку той ячейки, на которой установлен фокус. Вот как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если в этой ячейке начать что то писать или просто щелкнуть по ней 2 раза - становится вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно изменить вот эту ячейку, в которой установлен курсор? Я хочу что бы у нее была красная рамка. Заранее спасибо всем за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Переопределите `JTable.prepareEditor(TableCellEditor, int, int)`:

```
@Override
public Component prepareEditor(TableCellEditor editor, int row, int column) {
    final Component editorComponent = super.prepareEditor(editor, row, column);
    if ( editorComponent instanceof JComponent ) {
        ((JComponent)editorComponent).setBorder( new LineBorder( Color.RED ) );
    }
    return editorComponent;
}
```

Метод вызывается при активации редактирования, и в самой `JTable` получает у `TableCellEditor` визуальный компонент, который отображается при редактировании.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ от zRrr - просто отличный! Но его можно еще улучшить, если устанавливать цвет рамки редактора не абсолютный (Color.RED), а относительный - например, цвет фона выделенной ячейки таблицы:
((JComponent)editorComponent).setBorder(new LineBorder(getSelectionBackground()));